# Algebraic simplification of a function arising from Poisson's Formula

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-differential-equations

In a past-exam for my PDE class, there is a question involving finding a solution to the Laplace equation (in radial terms) at a boundary $f(\theta)=\cos \theta$

> Consider the Laplace equation in a circular domain of radius $a>0$. Given that the general solution $u(r,\theta)$ of this equation in polar coordinates
>   $$u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta}=0, \quad r<a$$
>   which additionally satisfies the boundary condition
>   $$u(a,\theta)=f(\theta)$$
>   is given by Poisson's formula
>   $$u = \frac{a^2-r^2}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(\xi)}{a^2-2ar\cos(\theta-\xi)+r^2} \mathrm{d}\xi$$ 
>   Find the solution, using Poisson's formula, when $f(\theta)=\cos \theta$, given that one may use without proof:
>   $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos z}{1-\alpha \cos z} = 2\pi\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{\alpha\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}, \quad |\alpha|<1$$

Substituting the boundary condition and integrating is not difficult, and one reaches to the solution:

$$u=\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{a^2+r^2} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{4a^2r^2}{(a^2+r^2)^2}}}{\frac{2ar}{a^2+r^2} \sqrt{1-\frac{4a^2r^2}{(a^2+r^2)^2}}}$$

the annoyance arrives in the following, by simplifying (given that $0<r<a$):

\begin{align}
\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{a^2+r^2} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{4a^2r^2}{(a^2+r^2)^2}}}{\frac{2ar}{a^2+r^2} \sqrt{1-\frac{4a^2r^2}{(a^2+r^2)^2}}}
=&\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{2ar} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{4a^2r^2}{(a^2+r^2)^2}}}{ \sqrt{1-\frac{4a^2r^2}{(a^2+r^2)^2}}}\\
=&\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{2ar} \frac{1-\frac{1}{a^2+r^2}\sqrt{(a^2+r^2)^2-4a^2r^2}}{ \frac{1}{a^2+r^2}\sqrt{(a^2+r^2)^2-4a^2r^2}}\\
=&\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{2ar} \frac{a^2+r^2-\sqrt{(a^2+r^2)^2-4a^2r^2}}{ \sqrt{(a^2+r^2)^2-4a^2r^2}}\\
=&\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{2ar} \frac{a^2+r^2-\sqrt{a^4+2a^2r^2+r^4-4a^2r^2}}{ \sqrt{a^4+2a^2r^2+r^4-4a^2r^2}}\\
=&\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{2ar} \frac{a^2+r^2-\sqrt{a^4-2a^2r^2+r^4}}{ \sqrt{a^4-2a^2r^2+r^4}}\\
=&\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{2ar} \frac{a^2+r^2-\sqrt{(a^2-r^2)^2}}{ \sqrt{(a^2-r^2)^2}}\\
=&\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{2ar} \frac{a^2+r^2-\sqrt{(r^2-a^2)^2}}{ \sqrt{(r^2-a^2)^2}}\\
=&\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{2ar} \frac{a^2+r^2-|r^2-a^2|}{ |r^2-a^2|}\\
\end{align}
Since $0<r<a$ then $r^2<a^2$ then $|r^2-a^2|=a^2-r^2$
\begin{align}
=&\cos \theta \frac{a^2-r^2}{2ar} \frac{a^2+r^2-(a^2-r^2)}{ (a^2-r^2)} \\
=&\cos \theta \frac{2r^2}{2ar}\\
u=&\cos \theta \frac{r}{a}
\end{align}
which is the desired solution.

Since is this on an previous exam I should expect to maybe encounter solutions of similar complexity. Is there anyway I can simplify the solution in a much faster manner since there are many terms arising from the  binomial $(a^2+r^2)$ such as $2ar$ or $4a^2r^2$ when it is squared.

I don't want to spend too much time on the exam trying to simplify such things at the risk of making a stupid algebraic error causing me to get stuck.

Can anyone give me any quick algebraic realizations one can see to arrive to the solution quicker?

Comment: Can you include the full PDE including boundary conditions in the question, for context?

Comment: @Dylan Sure one moment

Comment: @Dylan It has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're looking for.

There is a way to "see" the solution without doing the integral. If you're familiar with separation of variables, the general solution of Laplace's equation on a disk has the form

$$ u(r,\theta) = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n}\big(A_n\cos (n\theta) + B_n\sin (n\theta)\big) $$

The boundary condition reads

$$ u(a,\theta) = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n\big(A_n\cos(n\theta)+B_n\sin(n\theta)\big) = \cos(\theta) $$

When comparing terms, the only non-zero coefficent is $A_1 = \frac{1}{a}$, so the solution is

$$ u(r,\theta) = \frac{r}{a}\cos(\theta) $$

**Edit:** Your working is pretty much correct. If you want to be more efficient, consider reducing the square root first:

\begin{align} 
\sqrt{1-\alpha^2} &= \sqrt{1-\frac{4a^2r^2}{(a^2+r^2)^2}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{a^4 - 2a^2r^2 + r^4}{(a^2+r^2)^2}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{(a^2-r^2)^2}{(a^2+r^2)^2}} \\ 
&= \frac{a^2-r^2}{a^2+r^2} 
\end{align}

Then

\begin{align} 
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{\alpha\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}} &= \frac{1-\frac{a^2-r^2}{a^2+r^2}}{\frac{2ar(a^2-r^2)}{(a^2+r^2)^2}} \\
&= (a^2+r^2)\frac{(a^2+r^2)-(a^2-r^2)}{2ar(a^2-r^2)} \\ 
&= (a^2+r^2)\frac{2r^2}{2ar(a^2-r^2)} \\
&= \frac{r}{a}\frac{a^2+r^2}{a^2-r^2}
\end{align}

and the rest follows.

Comment: Ironically, I have reduced the question as written, for the sake of not having to explain the whole exam question. In actuality the first part of the question asks given that the solution is the general infinite series you have written, then show that the solution is Poisson's Formula. Then the second part of the question asks to use the Poisson's formula (and the associated $\cos$ integral) which has been derived in the first part and solve it using the boundary condition given.. I had already made the discovery you have, but unfortunately the professor wants it shown using Poisson's

Comment: Sorry for the slight deception, I have updated the question to make sure it is clear that Poisson's formula needs to be used

Answer (score 1):

Here, the method of **Separation of Variables** is very efficient and useful. In fact any answer to the above Laplace equation has a general answer as follows:$$u(r,\theta)=e_0+e_1\ln r+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_nr^n+b_nr^{-n})\cdot(c_n\cos n\theta+d_n\sin n\theta)$$The boundedness on $0<r<a$ implies that $$e_1=0\\b_n=0$$therefore$$u(r,\theta)=e_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n(\hat c_n\cos n\theta+\hat d_n\sin n\theta)$$and finally by imposing the boundary conditions we conclude:$$u(r,\theta)={r\over a}\cdot\cos\theta$$

**Edit**

If you want to simplify your fraction in a faster manner, note that$$\sqrt{1-{4a^2r^2\over (r^2+a^2)^2}}={r^2-a^2\over r^2+a^2}$$

Comment: Please see my comment to @Dylan's answer. I have made the same realization as you have, but the examiner wants it done through Poisson's integral. So it remains to simplify the solution after the integration in a faster manner